# Makeifle: if condition block in define block

Tags: if-statement, makefile

I create a `define block`

I'd like to check the program whether in the $PATH env.var,

i.e. whether program exists.

```
define CheckProgExist
    @$(eval exist=$(shell ${1} ${2} 2> /dev/null))
    @$(info ${1} ${2})
    @$(info ${exist})
    ifneq (${exist},"")
        @$(error "${1} does not exist in the $${PATH} of env.var")
    endif
endef
```

### First Line: `@$(eval exist=$(shell ${1} ${2} 2> /dev/null))`

Check command exists,

- `${1}` is command I specify
- `${2}` flags of program which I can check if program exists, generally:

  - return version message (to *stdout*) if program exists
  - return *null*(maybe) if program doesn't exist, because I've redirected *stderr* to null, output should be *null*

### Second line: `@$(info ${1} ${2})`

Display argument I input.

### Third line: `@$(info ${exist})`

Display content of variable, if

- ${1} exists, ${exist} should be message of version and program
- ${2} does not exists, ${exist} should be empty (or `null`)

### Fourth Line: `ifneq (${exist},"")`

If variable does not exist, then abort makefile

---

For example, I'd like to check whether `ls` exist:

```
chk_env_hw:
    @$(call CheckProgExist,ls,--version)
```

If program `ls` does not exist, then error message will display.

But the result seems strange:

```sh
>$ make
ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.32 Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>. This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
Makefile:11: *** "ls does not exist in the ${PATH} of env.var".  Stop.
```

`ls` is exist but the result shows not.

---

fully code

```
define CheckProgExist
    @$(eval exist=$(shell ${1} ${2} 2> /dev/null))
    @$(info ${1} ${2})
    @$(info ${exist})
    ifneq (${exist},"")
        @$(error "${1} does not exist in the $${PATH} of env.var")
    endif
endef

chk_env_hw:
    $(call CheckProgExist,ls,--version)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. `ifneq (${exist},"")` will fire the error if `${exist}` is not equal to `""`, which is the case. Try `ifneq (${exist},)`.
2. `ls --version` sends its output to the standard output, not the standard error, so in your case, with `ls --version`, `exist` will not be the empty string. It will be something like `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.32...`
3. What you're doing is a strange mixture of make and shell constructs. Make recipes are shell scripts. There is no need to call the `shell` make function in a recipe. You should maybe try to write a make macro with 100% shell content (including shell variables if you need some). Do not forget to escape the make expansion if needed.

You could try something like (not tested):

```
define CheckProgExist
@command -v '$(1)' > /dev/null || { echo "$(1) does not exist"; exit 1; }
endef

.PHONY: chk_env_hw

chk_env_hw:
    $(call CheckProgExist,ls)
```

(edited to use `command -v` as suggested by [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) instead of the non-POSIX `which`).

Comment: 1st, I replace `ifneq (${exist},"")` with `ifneq (${exist},)`, I still get same error messages

Comment: because of problem number 2

Comment: I tried `$(call CheckProgExist,lsx)` , I get `make: 'chk_env_hw' is up to date. `lsx` is invalid command. I wish this condition can report error and abort Makefile. The result message same to `$(call CheckProgExist,ls)` 
`

Comment: You probably have a file named `chk_env_hw`. Make thus considers that there is nothing to do because it exists already. Make it phony to tell make that this target is not a file and must be made even if a file with the same name exists. See my updated answer.

Comment: Plus: there was a typo in my answer (`define chk_env_hw` instead of `define CheckProgExist`). I fixed it too.

Comment: I wouldn't use `which` as it's not standard.  Much simpler and more portable is to use `command -v`.  Something like, `command -v '$(1)' >/dev/null || { echo "$(1) does not exist"; exit 1; }`

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for this information. I did not know that `which` is not standard (it even exists on AmigaOS...) The drawback of `command -v` is that it behaves quite differently and will be happy if an alias exists with that name, even if it aliases to a non-existing command. While `which` does not care about aliases. I'll add a note about this to my answer.

Comment: That's true but unlikely to matter for make recipes since there will not be any shell aliases there.  `which` is not part of the POSIX standard so there are minimal systems that don't have it, and because it's not standardized it may behave differently on different systems.

Comment: @MadScientist You're right, aliases are not a problem in the context of recipes. I replaced my `which`-based proposal by yours.